# Icons will not align with the text element

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an account page (header) for the first time, and I notice that some of the icons will not align perfectly with the text. I know how simple and easy this is for advanced developers, but I'm just starting off and really need some advice.

I have tried using padding and margin as a style element but didn't work.

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
               <img src="paylocity_logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:100%"S/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="project-details">
            <a class="home-link" href="" title="Edit">  <i class="material-icons"> home </i> </a>
            <div class="project">
              <a href="">User Profile</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-right" id="account">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="user-profile" title="Manage"> <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i> <span>Tom Markart </span></a>
        <div id="account-options">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="https://codepen.io/bmico/live/ZZZBGx"><span> <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></span>View Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-bug"></span>Report a Bug </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>Log Out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I want to make them straight.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Try adding a span around the text and apply `vertical-align:middle;` to the icon and text spans. e.g. `<a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span><span>Settings</span></a>` : `#account-options li span {vertical-align:middle;}`. Note that sometimes the actual font awesome icons arn't vertically centered properly, so you may need to add a pixel or 2 margin top to compensate.

Comment: You can use display: flex on the wrapper/parent element and justify-content: 'center' to align horizontally and align-items: 'center' to align vertically. ..and you have broken html tag in 'View Profile'  li element

Comment: What about `display: inline` or `float: right`?

Comment: It looks like a lot of this relies on some classes you're using via CSS. Can you include everything that is determining the placement? Classes like "home-link", "project" - Throw a codepen together or include everything in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can add the following rule:

```
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EBBbpd

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex`:
Wrap text in `<span>` and a wrapper class to `<a>`.

```
...
<li>
    <a class='wrapper' href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="fa fa-cog"></span>
        <span>Settings</span>
    </a>
</li>
...


.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center
}
```